# RadioGroupTabs - Tooltips

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

Good Morning,
I'm using the DocuSign api and creating a RadioGroupTab.  The Tooltip contains the Group when this hovers.  Is there a way to turn this off?

Thanks,
-Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, you cannot completely remove the tooltip, but you can customize it with the values you wish to show.